# godaddy VM with 2GB RAM or using Desktop with 16 or 32GB RAM as server?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines

[Godaddy VM Offering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdwLx.png)

What is the difference from server guys eyes... as a startup.
I have a personal desktop machine with i7 processor QuadCore and 32GB memory..
I can use it as a server as starting point..

Since I'm using it myself...
the 2GB offer from godaddy or in fact from anyone doesn't sound great ?

What is your say ?

Comment: Does your desktop have ECC ram, multiply-redundant power, multiply-redundant multihomed internet connection? How about server grade disks? How about a dedicated staff to monitor environmental parameters and fix air conditioning? Didn't think so. You may have a well-provisioned desktop, but a server it is not.

Comment: Server for yourself?  That is extremely vague.  Your server requirements will vary based on your server needs.  Are you just trying to add some convenience to your life; desktop server is probably a perfect starting point.  Or does your income and 1000's of users and their incomes rely on your server being available at all times?  Then you need the godaddy plan.  Or, or, or....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a server, purchase or rent a server.

Running a "server" on anything but server-grade hardware is irresponsible and short-sighted.